# Populating Excel Workbook with cell by cell values

Tags: sql, excel

I have a requirement to populate an Excel Workbook (somewhere between 10-15 sheets) with data outputs from various hardware tests. The sheets in the workbook are all different, and each of their cells (between 100-200 per sheet) are calculated based on specific formulas.

The team has taken a current approach of taking the output CSV, converting to JSON, and then openpyxl to map to specific cells.

There is no database used, and I think a DB in general is a good idea for testing. My thought was to ETL data into a DB, and from the excel workbook, generate queries for each cell from that DB.

I would need at least 2 DB, 1 for active tests (between 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 records) and 1 for archive/data warehousing (storage for old tests).

What do you think about the database proposal? I am just seeing all the technical debt we have incurred from writing so many bespoke python/bash scripts to structure data (CSV-JSON-Openpyxl)...custom libraries, classes etc. Other than feeling silly for potentially running a few hundred SQL queries in an excel workbook at a time...I feel like this is a really "clean" and simple way to approach this problem.

Appreciate thoughts and feedback